# Отвечаете ли вы на слова благодарности в комментариях?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии

Мне часто под ответом пишут слова благодарности. И в ответ всегда хочется сказать что-то вроде "не за что" или "был рад помочь". Но я понимаю, что такой комментарий не несёт никакого смысла. Но появляется некое чувство вины, мол человек мог подумать, что я его проигнорировал.

Как вы в таких ситуациях поступаете?

Comment: Я отвечаю, в конце-концов, мы ведь тут не роботы?

Comment: @VladD да, но обычно комментарии использую для уточнения вопроса/ответа. А слова благодарности к таким явно не относятся =/

Comment: Это да. Но за неимением другого канала обратной связи комментарии _можно_ немного использовать не по назначению. (Как мне кажется.)

Comment: @VladD конечно можно. Если увижу, что комментарий «Спасибо» отмечен как «более не является необходимым », наверняка отклоню тревогу.

Comment: Спасибо, что подняли этот вопрос!

Comment: @NickVolynkin а потом у участника статистика хромает из-за таких модераторских отклонений. И всякие [предупреждения выводятся](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291005/339911) не совсем приятные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а как же [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): _**Когда не следует оставлять комментарий?** Комплименты, не содержащие новой информации («+1, великолепный ответ»); вместо этого, проголосуйте за данный ответ и поделитесь своей репутацией._

Comment: @Grundy хороший вопрос. Думаю, что для автора можно сделать исключение, если он уже принял ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а если не принял не делать исключений? :-)

Comment: @Grundy если не принял — напоминать, чтобы принял. Это важнее.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Я почему-то перестал этого делать, предполагая, что это несёт вред сообществу да и модераторам в первую очередь - так как они стараются удалять подобные комментарии. Но мне искренне всегда хочется ответить на подобные сообщения, ведь, когда тебе  пишут слова благодарности, как-то странно отвечать молчанием =( У меня был некий диссонанс по этому поводу. Но теперь почитав данный пост буду отвечать таким людям добрыми словами ) Спасибо.

Comment: @Denis640Kb мы не ходим и не удаляем намеренно такие комментарии. Лично я только по тревогам)

Answer (score 6):

Обычно я отвечаю на подобные комментарии, если для решения проблемы потребовалось больше коммуникаций, чем просто из гугла копирнуть код в ответ. В таких случаях комментариями исписано всё под вопросом и ответом, лишняя пара комментов беды не сделает.

В простых случаях в комментариях действительно, ИМХО, нет смысла и, чтобы не расстраивать юзера, я просто лайкаю его коммент.

Comment: Лайк комментов часто неправильно интерпретируется новичками. Они могут лайкать все реплаи подряд (дополнительно может быть ожидая, что это еще добавит репутации автору комментария), хотя стоило бы только те, которые действительно добавляют важную информацию сообщению.

Comment: Да, такое тоже бывает. Но, когда этих комментов уже море то, по хорошему, надо бы не лайкать а избраться в модераторы и всё потереть, убедив участников перенести важное в вопрос/ответ. Но, т.к. переносят далеко не всегда, а инфа там может быть полезная то, думаю, придётся закрывать глаза на бардак в комментах или переностить всё в чат. Хотя я помню как лично меня расстраивало, когда @Nofate такие дисскуссии с моим участием в чат переносил. Мне лично в чате хуже - там сложнее будущим посетителям вопроса всё это читать, ибо лишний переход по сайту надо делать.

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от ситуации. Порой идет по сценарию, описанному @ЮрийСПб (но без лайков). Но сейчас задумался о том, что можно поступать иначе. Замечено, что даже если комментарий удаляется, оповещение о комментарии (даже с текстом) вполне может быть видно получателю. То есть можно и "этикет" соблюсти и сайт не засорять. Дополнительно можно отметить комментарий автора со "спасибами" тревогой как "более ненужный", чтобы ближайший модератор вымел его своей модераторской метлой. Если не очень доверяете доставке быстро удаленного сообщения, то можно это удаление отсрочить — свой комментарий не удалять самостоятельно, а понадеяться, что глазастый модератор удалит его вместе с флагнутым комментарием вашего оппонента. Модераторов скоро станет больше, так что можно попробовать на досуге ;)

Comment: Думаю не стоит модераторов перегружать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это не повод не флагать ненужный комментарий оппонента.

Comment: На самом деле мне ваше предложение нравится, но, возможно, я изменю мнение на сей счёт через неделю)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тогда придется изменить его, чтобы переголосовать :)

Comment: Тогда его можно будет и потереть))) Мву-ха-ха)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пойду поменяю голоса тогда ... :-D

Comment: Ну вот( Сколько вам плюсов накидать чтоб голоса не менялись? =)))